# Remove keras loss averaging behavior

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am having some difficulties understanding this behaviour of Keras during training.

At every epoch the loss goes down very smoothly. Then at the next epoch first step the loss steps down abruptly. So on for every epoch, having a loss plot which looks like and exponential stair going down. (see picture)

[image]

I think this is due from the fact that keras is averaging the loss over the epoch automatically, but this looks very ugly!

How can I remove this behaviour? I don't find it documented anywhere, but it's the only explanation I can give to this plot as

- the model is not overfitting as validation metrics are going okay
- keras is doing this something similar for metrics already (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ProgbarLogger: ref stateful_metrics)

Comment: This seems like an expected result. Assuming an epoch is defined as a pass over the entire dataset, at the end of each epoch it's reverting to data that has already been seen before. One would expect the loss for these items to be much lower than the loss for data which the model has only seen once. If you really dont want a graph like this you should either 1) change how you're definind an epoch of data, 2) render your own graph with a low pass filter to smooth it out. To me, though, you want your graph to be accurate, and this is telling you useful information. I don't see a problem.

Comment: For instance, a useful theory you could conclude from this graph is that having seen data before is more important than seeing more/newer data. This might mean you're memorizing your dataset (overfitting) instead of learning generalizable information. I have no idea, but this is a useful nugget of information which may make pursuing, for instance, regularization strategies more enticing. It may also mean nothing, and be a natural result of batching your data into epochs. There's a million ways to read a graph like this, but imho, it's better to see the real results than look to aesthetics.

Comment: Hey Warlax, I tought about this, but it is not the case as the steps_per_epoch (500k) doesn't match the dataset size (800k). This is why I think it is due to some averaging during the tensorflow epoch (which reports a higher loss, averaging with the precedent values), which is reset at the beginning of the epoch

Comment: Can you include a smalll snippet of your code that is responsible for batching your dataset into epochs?

Comment: `dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files)`
`dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: parse_tf_record(x))`
`dataset = dataset.unbatch().batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(AUTOTUNE)`
`dataset = dataset.repeat(count=-1)`

Comment: The loss is added through add_loss `self.add_loss(loss)`